# What is the cause of this stack overflow?

Tags: java, android, recursion, stack-overflow

I am writing a function in Java for an Android application that uses a `StringBuilder` to generate all permutations of a string.

Whenever the function is run, the program instantly terminates, and the DDMS (Dalvic Virtual Machine debugging tool) claims a stack overflow within my function.

```
private void reorder(String reorder_this, StringBuilder in_this){

    for(int i = 0; i < reorder_this.length(); i++)
    {
        if(i == reorder_this.length())
        {
            in_this.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        }
        else
        {
            in_this.append(reorder_this.charAt(i));
            reorder(reorder_this.substring(0, i) + reorder_this.substring(i), in_this);
        }
    }
}
```

You can see that I have taken a recursive approach to this problem, which I believe will end up filling the string builder with all possible permutations of the inputted string each followed by the newline character.

Does anybody have an idea about what could be causing the stack overflow?

Comment: Have you traced the execution through with a small string, like "ABC"? (I mean traced "by hand", or in a pinch, logging... but "playing computer" can really help.)

Comment: I found a much more efficient solution in nested for loops. I had been using scheme a lot recently, and had been stuck in the recursive paradigm.

Comment: Non-tail-recursive functions are often less efficient; recursion often shines because of how it communicates, not necessarily how it performs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, your function cannot terminate unless your string has a length of 0.

Your method begins with setting `i` to 0 and testing whether `i` is less than length of your first argument.  If it is (which will be the case for all but empty strings), you immediately recurse because you can not be strictly less than the length **and** equal to the length.  In your recursive call, you pass in a string of exactly the same length (indeed, the same exact string, as Thilo points out).  This indicates a second problem with the algorithm: recursive algorithms should operate on "smaller" arguments for each recursive call.

It will not take long to get a `StackOverflowException` here.  Each recursive call pushes a new stack frame.

Comment: True, `reorder_this.substring(0, i) + reorder_this.substring(i)` will just be the same as `reorder_this` again.

Comment: It's not even reached in that case. 0 is never < 0.

Comment: @EJP, I think my claim is correct because the method can only terminate if the for-loop completes.  That is what I was calling the "base case" although my terminology is probably confusing because it is easy to take the "base case" as the content of the if-clause.  Because the OP recurses before advancing in the for loop, the "base case" of **finishing the loop** is never reached _unless the original string is empty_.  So yes, the true-part of the if-statement is never reached, as I believe you are pointing out.  But that true-part is not what I would call a base-case because it is in a loop.

Comment: Ah, I see. The my problem is rooted in my misunderstanding of the substring function. It looks like the second argument to it actually indicates the index before the one specified.

Comment: @Ray Toal it is the base case because it is the one that doesn't recurse. Looping has nothing to do with it.

Comment: The fact that it is in the loop makes it confusing, I'll agree.  I'll reword the answer.  +1 for the technicality.  I have removed the confusing term "base case".

Comment: @EJP sorry to be pedantic but looping very much **does** affect this (as written).  IF the input string is empty, the method *will indeed* terminate, but not because it reaches the if-condition, just because of the way the loop is written.

Answer (score 2):

The cause of any stack overflow in Java is infinite recursion.

```
private void reorder(String reorder_this, StringBuilder in_this){
    for(int i = 0; i < reorder_this.length(); i++)
    {
        if(i == reorder_this.length())
        {
```

This block is unreachable, by construction. So your termination condition is never met.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is this line:

```
reorder(reorder_this.substring(0, i) + reorder_this.substring(i), in_this);
```

`reorder_this.substring(0, i) + reorder_this.substring(i)` will product a string equivalent to `reorder-this`